# Cannot use HP Officejet 4500 scanner except as root

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, scanner

The 4500 is an all-in-one device (printer/scanner/fax) and connected via USB cable.  I can
successfully print to it as non-root.

I am running Lubuntu and under the "Start" menu I can launch Graphics
--> Simple Scan.  After launching I see in the GUI:

```
No scanners detected
Please check your scanner is connected and powered on
```

When I run /usr/bin/simple-scan from the command line as root I can
scan.  So, seems like permissions, but what file/s would I need to
open up so that I can scan without being the root user?  My user is in the plugdev group.

```
$ grep plugdev /etc/group
plugdev:x:46:jason
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indicate the make of your scanner (the model number is nice, but insufficient) and how it's connected.

Comment: I also wonder why you would even try scanning as root? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo I really hope sudo simple scan does not break it.

Comment: Is your user in the `plugdev` group?

Comment: This problem stopped after I upgraded to (L)Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: If still, problem persists then you may contact this support link >> https://123hpprintersupport.com/hp-envy-4500-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away after updating to a later version of Ubuntu:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```